# Reading Three Pin Values

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded

I have three pins to read (not directly - from an upper layer). These pins can take on three values.
Signal high, Signal low, and open address.
Signal high would be a value of:
    (x =< 0.2); 
Signal low would have a value between:
    (> 0.2 x < 0.9)
And open address would be:
    (x >4.5).

What would be the best way to code this in C????

Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: "What would be the best way to code this in C?" Open an editor and type the program code.

Comment: Ummm.. reading the ADC section of your uC user manual seems like a good place to start.

Comment: I'm asking for an algorithm to read in a voltage based on a pin and output either high, low, or open address. If i was asking to read the ADC i would post in EE...

Comment: Nice attitude complaining getting a well meant and reasonable comment! You should be more clear about what you ask and show the code you alread have!

Comment: OK, in that case, have a close vote for 'unclear what you are asking'.  Pins don't have three values when read digitally, so you are reading analog, so you need A->D.  If you ask unclear questions, you will get inappropriate answers/comments.

Comment: @user3475003 what result would you want from the value 1.0?

Comment: Like the first two comments didn't have an condescending tone.

Comment: Well, @user3475003, it's a silly question.  C does not have a standard pin library that handles trinary data.

Comment: @MartinJames to be picky, a digital circuit *can* have three states: tri-state logic allows a high impedance state in addition to the logic levels 0 and 1.

Comment: Nevertheless, C has no standard libs for tri-state logic and if an o/p is tri-stated, there is no way to read its value.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is trivial:

```
enum {ERROR, SIGNAL_HIGH, SIGNAL_LOW, OPEN_ADDRESS};

int signal_to_value (double signal)
{
    if (signal <= 0.2)
        return SIGNAL_HIGH;
    else if (0.2 < signal && signal < 0.9)
        return SIGNAL_LOW;
    else if (signal > 4.5)
        return OPEN_ADDRESS;
    else
        return ERROR;
}
```

As you say in comments, how you get the signal and interpret the value is up to you.